# Advanced custom date range in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Im working with fullcalendar and the scheduler plugin. What im trying to do is having some more advanced date range.
I input a JS array a start time and differents duration. It should then create the range accordingly.

Here's an example
**Inputed array :** array = [ 30min, 30min, 120min, 30min, 9h ]
**Outputed date range :**
9h, 9h30, 10h, 13h, 13h30

Regarding the scheduler im fine, i've done it in the **rangeUpdated** and **updateGridDates** functions and it works pretty well.
My concern is about the calendar since im a bit lost in the source code and i can't really find the place where I should do the logic for this.

Can any kind soul guide me througt this ?
Thank's in advance

Comment: Ok, im starting to get something but i'm stuck again.
What I did is play around with the **renderSlatRowHtml** function to display custom time range. However, I can't get the view (where events are being rendered) to be correct, it still try to render other events.
Here is a JSFiddle describing the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbs5uafd/3/
You can see the 1px blue event at the very bottom.

Comment: Still stuck and can't figure out what to do :/
May really appreciate some help !

Comment: Im currently investigating on the role of the **computeTimeTop** function which seems to be related to slat coverage and top position. If anyone has any hint.. it's welcome

Answer (score 0):

So, I resolved my issue by doing the math in the **computeTimeTop** function. It is responsible for the calculation of the event position on the grid. I had to compute the position of the given time by locating between which slat it should be placed.